# How can start contributing to Ros Development

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have previously worked on path planning for self driving vehicle at Autonomous Ground Vehicle Research Group in my college. I have worked on ROS and Gazebo and designed a planner for the vehicle based on ROS Navigation Stack. I am a beginner at open source programming. I wanted to inquire about the projects I can contribute for the development of Ros as a part of GSoc 15. It would be great to be associated with such a wonderful organisation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201931/how-can-start-contributing-to-ros-development/) by [yvshri](https://answers.ros.org/users/21505/yvshri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some possible projects listed at: http://wiki.osrfoundation.org/gsoc15 for GSoc 2015. You can also create your own. Find a package which you want to contribute to and consider contacting the maintainer to propose a project.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3